# Show that there is $z_0$ on the unit circle such that $|p(z_0)|>1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $p(z)=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\dots+a_0$.  Prove that if $p(z)\neq z^n$, then there is $z_0$ on the unit circle such that $|p(z_0)|>1$.  *Hint: Consider $q(z)=z^np(1/z)$*.

I have really been messing around with $q(z)$, I have considered the case when $|z|=1$ (since that would put $z$ on the unit circle.  I have done many other things, tried Triangle Inequality, Lower Triangle Inequality, etc.  I just can't seem to find the required clever step to solve this.

I am only looking for a hint, please, as this is a homework problem.  By hint, I mean a tad bit more of a hint than the one that is given in the problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
Suppose $|p(z)|\leq 1$ for all $|z|=1.$ Note that $|p(z)|=|q(\bar{z})|$ for $|z|=1$ and $q(0)=1.$ Using Maximum modulus principle, you will get $q(z)$ a constant and $p(z)=z^n$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: I thought that $q(0)$ was undefined.

Comment: Nevermind, I see it now.  Thanks for the help!